# What is Facebook Web Games on Facebook Developer Console

Tags: facebook

When I try to change settings in Facebook Developer Console(settings - basic), 'Facebook Web Games - Facebook Web Games URL (https)' says "The parameter is required". Why it's needed? My App is not a game. What I fill an url? Can I just safely remove the Facebook Web Games section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Games platform is what used to be called Canvas (before Facebook decided to use the latter term in their advertising platform.)

That is basically an app or website running on your server, embedded into facebook.com via an iframe. And then there’s the App Center resp. Games section on Facebook, where your app can present itself to try and find new users.

But if you are not using any of that, you can safely remove the Web Games platform from your app settings.